# Today's update did not go through

Tags: updates

I am using Kubuntu 22.04.1 on a Dell desktop
.
updates names all start with **libpam**
libpam-modules
libpam-modules-bin
libpam-runtime
libpam0g
.
**Here's the message:**
.
Package download failed:

```
E: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libpam0g amd64 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.3 is not (yet) available (Cannot initiate the connection to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out [IP: 91.189.91.39 80])
```

Comment: Try again later or change a mirror.

Comment: I don't know how to change the mirror. Can you please help?

Comment: You can select it in Software & Updates app. But it looks like it is resolved.

Comment: Pilot6, I deleted my answer that was not an answer as you suggested.

Comment: Run `sudo apt update`. If it shows that all is up-to-date, then you are done.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Pilot6.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Ubuntu has just acknowledged the issue with the archives being down/overloaded 45 minutes ago. See below for the link to their status page. This is why you were getting the issue when you did the update.

https://status.canonical.com/

Archive servers overloaded
This incident has been open for 45 mins.
Incident Start Time
Feb 06, 2023 12:00 PM EST
Affected Components
cloud-images.ubuntu.com,  security.ubuntu.com,  archive.ubuntu.com,  nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com
Incident Status Updates
Acknowledged
An issue has been acknowledged and we are investigating further.
Posted on Feb 06, 2023 at 12:00 PM EST (45 mins ago)